# restoring volume from ebs snapshot empty

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've created a snapshot of an ebs with data on it. Then I tried to create a volume out of the snapshot and attach it to an instance. However when I try to mount the volume (with data), it says

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdg,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

And if I try to mkfs it, all data would be lost right?

Comment: What was your mount command? What is the fstab entry (if any)? What errors are shown by dmesg?